# how do you call a method from another react class component

Tags: reactjs

trying to learn react, and a bit confused about how to call another component on click..

**my button component:**

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from '.././Header.js'

class Login extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='Login'>
            <button id='login' onClick={ Header.incrementCount }>increment</button>
            </div>
        );
    };
}
export default Login;
```

**my class component:**

```
import React from 'react';
import Head from 'next/head'

export default class Header extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        count: 1,
      };
    }
    incrementCount = () => {
      this.setState({
        count:  this.state.count + 1
      });

    };
    render() {
      return (
        <Head>
        <title>/{this.state.count}</title>
        </Head>
      );
    }
};
```

i'm basically just trying to get the title of the page to increment with every click...but im getting no response

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html this might help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the function down as a prop to the child, so that the child can see it in its props and call it.

```js
class Login extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='Login'>
            <button id='login' onClick={ this.props.incrementCount }>increment</button>
            </div>
        );
    };
}
class Header extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        count: 1,
      };
    }
    incrementCount = () => {
      this.setState({
        count:  this.state.count + 1
      });

    };
    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <Login incrementCount={this.incrementCount} />
          <h3>/{this.state.count}</h3>
        </div>
      );
    }
};

ReactDOM.render(<Header />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

There could be multiple approaches to achieve this.

**If there is a Parent-Child relationship**

For example if `Logincomponent` is wrapped under `HeaderComponent` and LoginComponent wants to call HeaderComponent's APIs. For that passing method ref as the part of `props` is the best way which is explained in above post.

**If there is no relation between components**

In that case you can store HeaderComponent object reference to some global variable using `ref` feature of React and then access it in any component.

Try below code:

```
import React from "react";

var header;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header ref={(h) => { header = h; }}></Header>
      <Login></Login>
    </div>
  );
}


class Header extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      count: 0
    };

    this.addCount = this.addCount.bind(this);
  }

  addCount() {
    this.setState({
      count: ++this.state.count
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Count : {this.state.count}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Login extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  login() {
    header.addCount();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.login}>Login</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```